# Logic to find the number of requests which can be open at any point of time

Tags: logic

I am trying to build an application which tries to find out if a system is suffering from backlog (# of requests which are open are more than what the team can handle)

I have the below parameters alone and with these how can I find the 'ideal' number of open requests so that the system does not have any backlog.

```
Priority    # of Requests / Month   # of days to resolve
--------    --------------------    --------------------
P-1         45                      1
P-2         90                      2
P-3         90                      3
P-4         585                     5
P-5         90                      10
--------    --------------------    --------------------
Total       900
--------    --------------------    --------------------
```

Since each request has its own 'time to resolve', I cannot do 900/21 (# of working days in a month) = 42.85.

Any idea/advice?

Comment: What's the point of this exercise? There will always be a backlog that is larger than what you can handle in a sprint period. For most software the absence of such a backlog would just equal its deprecation anyways. What more do you want to get out of this than typical burndown-charts, etc. offer you already?

Comment: What does 'time to resolve' mean? Is it the effort it takes to resolve the request, or is it the time it can be left without action?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau its the time before which the requests should be processed

Comment: @Frank the point of this exercise is to identify, on a daily basis, if the system is having backlog..

Comment: Then you are missing some very crucial pieces of information: The number of requests that your team can process in a day and the pattern in which requests of the different priorities arrive. If the P-1 requests all arrive on the same day, but your team can't process that many requests, you have a problem no matter what.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - I dont have this piece of information. Is it possible to derive a logic without this information?

Comment: @kutekrish: If you don't have that information, the worst-case scenario becomes very simple: 0 requests processed, so 900 open at the end of the month (and 1800 after two months, etc.).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrum - Calculating Sprint Velocity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/321484/scrum-calculating-sprint-velocity)